# Returning a value from a worksheet to another

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with two worksheets, A & B.

I need a formula that will look at a value in cell B2 in worksheet A and return the value in cell F2 in worksheet A to cell C2 in worksheet B.

So.  If the value in B2 is individual the formula will return the Value in F2, e.g., "Smith", to cell C2 in worksheet B.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So, like this:

```
=IF('Sheet A'!B2="individual",'Sheet A'!F2,"Blank")
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply, thank you, though I realise my question wasn't detailed enough.  There are variables and I though I's be able to work out what I needed.   I've two screenshots of my worksheets.  Are you able to tell me how I add them here?

Comment: SheetAExampleID Name Format Title First Name Middle Last Name Suffix
Example0001 Business Mr John  Jones OBE
Example0002 Business  J  Robson 
Example0003 Family     
Example0004 Individual Dr John T Thompson 
Example0005 Individual Mr & Mrs John & Mary  Blakely 
Example0006 Individual Prof. Tom M Smith